# Number of permutations with a given property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinatorial-proofs

We say a permutation $\sigma$ of a set $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ has a property $A$ if for every $1\le k < n$, $$\sigma(\{1,\dots,k\})\not=\{1,\dots,k\}$$
Let $c_n$ be the number of such permutations, prove that the following equation holds

$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i(n-i)!=n!$$

Not sure how to aproach this, tried it for small numbers and i've got that $c_1=1,c_2=1,c_3=3,c_4=13$. Also not sure if i can somehow prove it combinatorialy with $i$ being lenght of a prefix of a permutation that satisfies property $A$.

For example for $S = \{1,2,3\}$
$$
\sigma=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\2&3&1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
works and $$\sigma_2=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&2&3\\2&1&3
\end{matrix}
\right)$$
doesn't since $\sigma_2(\{1,2\})=\{1,2\}$

Comment: I think it's meant as a mapping of sets there -- the image of $\{1,\dots,k\}$ is not itself.

Comment: @Paul No, it requires that $\sigma$ applied to any proper initial segment of $n$ permutes at least one element of the initial segment away from the initial segment.

Comment: I believe this is [A003319](https://oeis.org/A003319) in oeis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a permutation that has the property you mentioned "good".
You can show that there is a bijection between the set of all of the permutations on $[n]$ and the set $$\{(k,f,g) |k\in [n], f \text{ is a good permutation on } [k] \text{ and } g \text{ is a permutation on } \{k+1,...,n\}\}$$
By looking at the first $k$ such that $f[k]=[k]$ for some permutation. this proves the relation.

Comment: i am sorry is $[n]$ a set with $n$ elements?

Comment: Yes, $[n] := \{1,...,n\}$